# How do I know what parameters can be injected

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, dependencies, code-injection

I'm wondering where and if there's a documentation on what can be injected into a function with dependency injection.

I understand that all registered services/factories in angularjs can be injected but when stumbling upon a solution to a problem I had, I read about the following:

```
function AppController($scope, $element, $compile) {
  // ...
}
```

So from the tutorials I know $scope (but I did not find anything about $scope or scope in http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ - all I found was $rootScope).

Same with the $element. But $compile is a service just like $http - I understand where they come from.

Obviously I'm missing a very basic point about dependency injection and would be happy if someone could explain it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rootScope` is an instance of `$scope`, and `$scope` docs are found here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

`$element` is implicitly injected into `compile`, `controller` and `linking` directive functions and is explained here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

While `$rootScope` can be explicitly injected anywhere you want, `$element` is available only inside the directives.

Comment: okay. I just realized that under the $compile-Section in the AngularJS-API actually what is explained is the Directive-Definition-Object (...? don't understand why...). But where is the module.controller-Function explained (not the directive-definition-object controller-property) with all it's injectable dependencies?